# $Y$ be real NLS ; if there is a Banach space $X$ such that there is a continuous linear open mapping from $X$ to $Y$ then is $Y$ a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ be a real normed linear space ; if there exist a Banach space $X$ such that there exist a continuous linear open mapping from $X$ to $Y$ then is $Y$ a Banach space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous, open linear map.

From openness follows surjectivity: let $y \in Y$, consider $B_1(0)_X \subset X$, then $f(B_1(0)_X)$ is open, thus contains some $B_\epsilon(0)_Y$. Then $\epsilon \frac{y}{2\|y\|} \in f(B_1(0)_X)$ and $y \in f(X)$.

Since $f$ is continuous the kernel is closed, since $X$ is Banach then $\tilde X :=X/\ker (f)$ is again a Banach space. The map $\tilde f : \tilde X \to Y$ is then a continuous, open linear bijection. The inverse map $\tilde{f}^{\,-1}$ is then also a continuous linear map. For each $y \in Y$ you have

$$\frac{\|\tilde f^{\,-1}(y)\|_X}{\|\tilde f^{\,-1}\|_\infty}≤\|y\|_Y=\left\|(\tilde f \circ \tilde f^{\,-1})(y)\right\|_Y≤\|\tilde f\|_\infty \|\tilde f^{\,-1}(y)\|$$

So the notions of convergence in $Y$ and $\tilde X$ are the same. This makes $Y$ complete since $\tilde X$ is complete.

Comment: But completeness is not a topological property: $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric is complete, $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ is not complete (the sequence $x_n=n$ is Cauchy but not convergent), but the two are homeomorphic. So somehow you need to use the fact that the metric is induced by a norm to finish the argument.

Comment: @Ian If there exists a norm that makes a topological vectorspace a Banach space, then every norm compatible with the topology makes hte space Banach: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1611892/152424

Comment: Yes, I agree that your argument works, I am just saying that this last step, "$Y$ has the same topology as a Banach space and is itself Banach", is not entirely trivial. It should be regarded as a lemma.

Comment: @Ian yes, you are right about it. The argument in the answer I have linked is however longer than the answer I have written here though, which is why I did not want to write it again in this answer. I put a link in my answer to the other question to make it more complete in that respect.

Comment: @s.harp You don't need to refer to that theorem. Once $\tilde f$ is a continuous open bijection you're done: $\tilde f$ and $\tilde f^{-1}$ are both continuous, hence both _bounded_, so $A||x||_X\le||\tilde fx||_Y\le B||x||_X$.  Hence $||.||_Y$ is complete.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that is quite a bit more elegant, I'll edit the answer

Comment: But for this, one would have to show that $\tilde f$ is open, right? I think it is not immediate that $\tilde f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp if $\tilde V$ is open in $\tilde X$ then $\pi^{-1}(\tilde V)$ is open in $X$ (if $\pi$ is the projection). Finally $\tilde f(\tilde V) = f(\pi^{-1}(\tilde V))$ is then open.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes. Luckily $\tilde f$ _is_ open...

Comment: Of course, it is. I just wanted to point out that it is not that immediate.