# Open mapping from a complete normed space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let X,Y be normed spaces and $T\in B(X,Y)$. Show that if X is complete and T is an open mapping, then Y is complete.

I found this problem is quite similar to open mapping theorem but they are different. I know that T should be surjective due to Barie's Category Theorem. However, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is the pre-image of a Cauchy sequence Cauchy?  Is the image of a limit the limit of the image?

Comment: @Gaffney That's the problem I'm facing. If I know that the pre-image of a Cauchy sequence Cauchy, I should get the result. But I don't know why it is Cauchy.

Comment: If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $(T(x_n))_n$ is Cauchy in $Y$ then $(x_n)_n$ is not necessarily Cauchy in $X.$ For example if $X=\mathcal R^2$ and $Y=\mathcal R,$ and $ T$ is the projection to the first co-ordinate, which is an open linear map. And $x_n=(1/n,n).$

Comment: @user254665 Then how to prove this proposition? Or this proposition is wrong?

Comment: I think the prop. is right. It might be useful that T must be a surjection.

Comment: You can find an answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697140/y-be-real-nls-if-there-is-a-banach-space-x-such-that-there-is-a-continuous/1697157#1697157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the proper version of the open mapping theorem, like e.g. in Rudin's book, you can indeed use it to prove completeness of quotients. The version you need is that every *almost open* (i.e. the closure of $S(B_X)$ contains some ball) continuous linear map $S:X\to Z$ from a Banach space $X$ to a normed space $Z$ is open (there is also a version for metrizable topological vector spaces).

Apply this to the completion $Z$ of $Y$ and $S(x)=T(x)$.

Comment: Ok, I see. My version is requiring that both spaces are complete. I will check that one.